# Prepared SQL WHERE Condition = "Any"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE A=:a, B=:b, C=:c";
```

The number of conditions depend on user input too (checkboxes). Are there any SQL commands that stand for 'any' so that the prepared statement

```
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE A=(any value), B=:b, C=:c";
```

is equivalent to

```
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE B=:b, C=:c";
```

If not can someone prepare an SQL with unknown number of conditions like all of the following 3?

```
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE B=5, C=7";
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE A=9, B=1, C=2";
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE C=10";
```

Comment: There's no such sql commands. You have to create `where` clause by yourself.

Comment: You need to generate a dynamic query via PHP based on your checkboxes.

Comment: Yes. I'm using a dynamic query now (string concatenation). So, one cannot use prepared statements in this circumstance?

Comment: If you are using a dynamic query as you say, then dynamically have the stuff disappear from your query where it is not appropriate